# convert json file to string present in a sd card

Tags: java, android, json

and print it in a text view. so that every time i run the app if the folder is present in sdcard then it fetches json fron there else it makes the folder and we insert the json manually in to it.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Title is too long and confusing.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I am converting the `bottomText.json` in `String` which was in SD card's *dor* folder or /sdcard/dor/bottomText.json and I used `TextView` to show it.

```
       FileReader inputStream = null;
            JSONObject obj1;


       try {


            String line,line1="";
            String path;
              File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
              File f=new File(sdcard+"/dor");

              f.mkdir(); 
                File file1 = new File(sdcard,"/dor/fitness.json");
                //file1.mkdir();
                // Assuming each link to be on a new line
             StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

                    String json1 = null;
                    try {

                        InputStream is1 = new FileInputStream(file1);

                        int size1 = is1.available();

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[size1];

                        is1.read(buffer);

                        is1.close();

                        json1 = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


             } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);    
      tv.setText(json1);
      } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: I know you're excited but please explain your posts (questions/answers) properly. It helps others in the future.

Comment: actually in the answer wat i hav done is converted bottomText.json in string which was in sdcard's dor folder or /sdcard/dor/bottomText.json and i used textview to show it